# programming exercise dont know what is the good answer

Tags: java

if i have this :

```
public class Test {

stotic int total = 10;

public static void moin (String args []) 
{

new Test

};


public Test() 
 {

System.out.println("In test" ) 
;

System.out.println(this);

int temp = this.total;

if (temp > 5) {

System.out.println(temp) ;

]

]

]
```

what will happen?
compile error or
the compile will show error at line 2 (the one with static total) or
will show 10 or
program will fail at line 9(int temp=this.total)

i dont know what to do here ...

Comment: How about you try to compile it and see what happens?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to compile and see for yourself.

Comment: you spelled `static` incorrectly on line 2 and you have 3 square brackets closing your code.  That's not gonna compile.

Comment: @GuntherFox I was hoping he was going for `stoic`...

Comment: @admdrew  That's a great idea for a new keyword.

Comment: Is this a "find the bugs" exercise?

Comment: @GuntherFox Behaves just like `static`, but doesn't complain if you try to change the value?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for?

Comment: @letsjak This edit was invalid. By fixing the typos, you changes the answer to the question "what will happen?" when this program compiles/runs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix some typos first:

- `stotic` => `static`
- `moin` => `Main`

Then there are these syntax errors:

- `new Test` => `new Test()`
- usage of `]` to close off scope / blocks.
  Use `}` to close off the corresponding blocks
- usage of this. to access a static field. Use Test.total not this.total (from @dognose's answer)

Comment: But if he fixes those typos, he probably won't get the right answer to the question how this program will fail.

Comment: IF that is his question then the way to get the answer is to compile it and see for himself : ]

Answer (score 0):

Answer you are seeking for - beside typos mentioned:

It will compile, but produce a warning (in the IDE), cause `total` is a `static` field of `Test`, which means, you should access it using `Test.total` and not `this.total`.

The compiler will fix this for you, so it will run fine and produe the following output:

```
In test
Test@[hashode] //hashcode may vary depending on instance.
10
```

ps.: If the typos are *no* typos, meaning the excercise is *as provided* - it won't compile, failing with the first error message, that `stotic` is an illegal identifier.